# GEE - extract temperature data for a large dataset of GPS locations

Tags: google-earth-engine, gps, extract, land-surface-temperature

I'm trying to extract mean temperature data for specific GPS locations across a large latitudinal/longitudinal range). I am using Google Earth Engine (new at this).

To get to the code I'm showing below, I used this source mostly: https://google-earth-engine.com/Terrestrial-Applications-part-2/Working-With-GPS-and-Weather-Data/

My input dataset, gps_data_file (.csv), looks like this:

```
gps_point_id  animal_id datetime                latitude    longitude
113166        26        2016-06-04 20:01:00 UTC 68.65458    12.74638
113171        26        2016-06-04 22:02:05 UTC 68.65193    12.77871
113172        26        2016-06-04 23:00:45 UTC 69.65795    12.70252
113111        26        2016-06-04 01:00:14 UTC 68.52357    12.87862
113121        26        2016-06-04 02:00:22 UTC 67.59134    12.83926
113125        26        2016-06-04 04:00:26 UTC 65.66744    12.84379
```

-> My **ideal output** would be this same file with an extra column indicating the mean daily temperature for each point at that specific day.

This file has **> 16000 GPS points**, with a **wide range of latitudes/longitudes**. In GGE, I first upload the `.csv` file through the "Assets" command, and then open it in the command line, with a few more lines to display the data in the map:

```
var animalData = ee.FeatureCollection('users/USER/gps_data_file');

Map.centerObject(animalData , 10);

Map.addLayer(animalData ,{}, 'animal GPS data');

print(animalData, 'animal data', animalData.limit(10));
```

All good so far. The columns of the imported file are integer (animal_id and gps_data_id) and string (datetime).
I then create a polygon(`geometry`; drawn in the map) in the map to cover only the area where my GPS locations are. And then I load the [temperature data](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/ECMWF_ERA5_DAILY#bands) :

```
// Call in image collection and filter.
var era5_2mt = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5/DAILY')
                   .select('mean_2m_air_temperature')
                   .filter(ee.Filter.date('2004-05-01', '2004-08-01'))
   .filterBounds(geometry)
   .map(function(image){
       return image.clip(geometry);
   });
```

My datetime range is much bigger, it spans from ***2004**-05-05* to ***2017**-07-21*. When I tried with this range, I got an error (`User memory limit exceeded`), which honestly was expected, as this is a huge amount of data...
To get to some output and see how the extraction would go, I then extracted data for only 3 months, as you can see in the code above.

I then converted this to a multiband image, following [the source I mentioned above](https://google-earth-engine.com/Terrestrial-Applications-part-2/Working-With-GPS-and-Weather-Data/) (Section 2.3):

```
var era5_2mtImage=era5_2mt.toBands();
```

And then I extract the data:

```
    // Call the sample regions function.
    var samples=era5_2mtImage.sampleRegions({
       collection: animalData,
       properties: ['gps_point_id'],
       scale: 1000
    });

     print(samples, 'samples', samples.limit(10));
```

This is the output of print (within properties I get the temperature values:

[image]

It looks good, so then I export the data to google drive:

```
// Export value added data to your Google Drive.
    Export.table.toDrive({
       collection: samples,
       description: 'lynx_temp_data_toDrive',
       fileFormat: 'csv'
    });
```

However, when I open this in R, I get a file with a column with the temperature for each day day (!!), so the file is huge (and it doesn't even have the whole time range, which is > 10 years...):

[image]

### So, my questions are :

**(1)** How to get the temperature value for the day corresponding to the date in my file? Basically, to get only one column with the temperature info (for that location on that specific day). This would reduce the size of the file a lot!

Ideally, the output would show me also the corresponding `gps_point_id`, so that I can then connect the two datasets.
I see that the information is stored in the "FeatureCollection" file, under the properties of each feature, but I'm not sure how to connect this?

**(2)** Can I improve the workflow, considering that I will be using such a bit dataset? And that I will run into the error (`User memory limit exceeded`).